# Todonotes problem: No line connecting notes to text

Tags: dvi, todonotes

When using the `todonotes` package, all notes are missing correct lines. That is, instead of having a line connecting the note and the text, the line connects to the note itself (with default color you cannot see this, since both the line and the background of the note has the same color; resulting in no line).

See code below and the result it produces.

What can the problem be?

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\author{name}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Bla bla bla \todo{where is the line?} Bla blah

More Blah, \todo{and now?} blah 

\end{document}
```

[image: example of failed todonotes]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using your code I got the lines working properly. Are you sure that the MWE provided gives the picture of your question?

Comment: You have to compile twice.

Comment: Indeed, when using WinEdt (and MikTex), the resulted dvi had also flawed lines, but the resulted PDF had correct lines. What's going on here?

Comment: By the way, what is MWE?

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Oh, DVI. The positioning of TikZ graphics aren't usually correct in DVI I think (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/tikz-with-positioning-does-not-work-with-dvi), you have to convert to PDF. I have no idea how Bakoma works, so I can't really help with that.