# Getting commutative diagrams in TikZ to work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'm new to making documents in LaTeX, though I've used just math mode for a while. I've installed `texlive-core` via `texlive-most` from the Arch repositories and rendered a few basic documents. However, when I try to render this (taken verbatim from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45747/56357)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em] {
     F_t(x) & F(x) \\
     A_t & A \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left] {$\mathcal{B}_X$} (m-2-1)
            edge [double] node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_t$} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} node [above] {$\exists$} (m-2-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} (m-2-2)
            edge [dashed,-] (m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't see any of the lines or arrows – just F_t(x), F(x), some letters written over each other, A_t and A in a roughly rectangular shape:

[image: What should have been a diagram]

And here's the log file, in which there seem to be no errors or warnings:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux) (format=latex 2014.6.30)  30 JUN 2014 22:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**comdia.tex
(./comdia.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
))
Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count87
\c@pgf@countb=\count88
\c@pgf@countc=\count89
\c@pgf@countd=\count90
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2013/07/16  (rcs-revision 1.23)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.def
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2008/10/01  (rcs-revision 1.22)
\pgf@objectcount=\count91
))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2013/12/13  (rcs-revision 1.23)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2013/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.44)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2013/09/19  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.40)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2013/10/31  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2013/07/31  (rcs-revision 1.12)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
matrix.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex 2013/07/12 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.4)
) (./comdia.aux)
\openout1 = `comdia.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
 [1

]
(./comdia.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10425 strings out of 493309
 216369 string characters out of 6143642
 250129 words of memory out of 5000000
 13741 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,12n,70p,410b,787s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on comdia.dvi (1 page, 9056 bytes).
```

I've heard that TikZ shouldn't be installed directly, but it's obviously not working properly. What should I do?

Comment: You've compiled to DVI, try compiling directly to PDF (with `pdflatex`), or converting the DVI to PDF.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/

Comment: Yes, thanks! So what's the point of DVI files?

Comment: If you were drawing with `pstricks`, you'd want to produce `ps` output via `dvi` as `pdflatex` cannot cope with postscript specials. More generally, `dvi` is an older format than `pdf`. `pdf` was not available when TeX was designed. I've never needed `latex` myself (rather than `pdflatex`) but some packages depend on that method of compilation. I guess that 'the point' is: different horses for different courses.

Comment: @cfr: pdflatex `can` cope with pstricks nowadays (at least in most cases) if you load it with the `pdf` option and compile with the `--enable-write18` or `--shell-escape`.

Comment: @James Wood: You probably should use the `tikz-cd` package.

Comment: @JamesWood The DVI format was developed more than 35 years ago and is basically unchanged. DVI viewers can cope with some “specials”, but not with all PostScript specials, as this would require a PostScript interpreter. For instance, no DVI viewer that I know is able to do arbitrary rotations. To the contrary, PDF viewers *are* able to show the result of TikZ constructions, because they do interpret the relevant specials.

Comment: @egreg But you can't produce postscript output directly, can you? Don't you compile with `latex` first and then post-process? And I know that `pdflatex` can cope with some postscript specials but there are still packages which use postscript in ways `pdflatex` cannot cope with. But I've never done any of this so perhaps I'm entirely mistaken...

Comment: @cfr The argument to a `\special` command is written “as is” in the DVI file. A conforming DVI viewer will ignore the specials it can't deal with, but it *can* interpret some of them. For instance, `xdvi` is capable of calling `ghostscript` for showing included EPS files, but not rotate them. In its DVI mode, TikZ/PGF uses PostScript specials that `xdvi` can't deal with. In PDF mode it uses PDF specials that, of course, PDF viewers are able to interpret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in order to close this post:

Here is your diagram drawn with help of the package `tikz-cd`. You should compile this directly with pdfLaTeX.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
     F_t(x) \arrow[double, swap, "\mathcal{B}_t"]{r} \arrow[swap, "\mathcal{B}_X"]{d} & F(x) \arrow["\mathcal{B}_T"]{d} \\
     A_t \arrow{r}[swap]{\mathcal{B}_T}{\exists} \arrow[dash, dashed]{ur}& A \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not working on Lua/XeLaTeX ?

Comment: @percusse It sure does. Just mentioned the "pdf"LaTeX as the OP was compiling to DVI before.