# Use of TikZ and Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am new to TikZ and I am trying to use it to display a very simple line. I also want a line of text on the page displayed above the line. Therefore, I wrote the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Here is a graph of $y = x^2$.
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw (-2,-2) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I view the output using the program yap the line is above the text. However, if I produce a PDF file by using the programs divps and ps2pdf the line is below the text which is the way I like it. I do not understand why there is a difference.

My current thinking is that I want to use TikZ to produce graphs for my documents but I am wondering if I would be better off producing the graphs in a different tool, such as GNU plot, and importing them in. I would like to know what you think of this idea?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: the picture is where had to be:under line `Here is a graph of $y = x^2$.` Tested with pdfLaTeX ("pdf" file) as well with LaTeX ("yap" file).

Comment: I am using yap as my previewer and the picture (the graph of a straight line) is above the text. I am using version of 2.9.5032. However, the generated PDF file comes out with the line below the text. Therefore I am confused.

Comment: I use 64-bit MikTeX, recent version with YAP 2.9.5640. For rendering method in YAP I select Dvips, however, it is not likely, that the YAP will show result so different than Adobe Reader or in my test Sumatra.

Comment: Well, I changed the rendering method to Dvips and it now displays the way I expected. If I change it back to Pk then it shows the line above. I am wondering, did I find a bug? If so, is there somebody I can report it to?

Comment: It is long time known, that rendering  with Pk has problems with presenting pictures, so this is not really bug. I so rarely use YAP (only if I had to use eps figures) , that I don't remember anymore, what exactly is caouse for this "misbehavior" of YAP ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rather an issue of YAP than a TeX problem.

Comment: See also [Tikz with positioning does not work with DVI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5826) and [TikZ/PGF figures messed in DVI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84182)