# TikZ ignores node positions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’m trying to write a simple finite state automaton in TikZ/LaTeX—The code should be quite self-explanatory:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{state}=[circle, draw]
  \tikzstyle{endstate}=[circle, draw, double]

  \node (start) at (-1, -1) {};
  \node (AS) at (1, 1) [state]{$A_S$};
  \node (AF) at (3, 1) [endstate]{$A_F$};

  \draw [->] (start) to (AS);
  \draw [->] (AS) to node [auto, near start] {a} (AF);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, LaTeX completely ignores the node positions, i.e. all three nodes are placed on top of each other. [image: The nodes are printed on top of each other.]

A similar code (which is quite long, so I won’t post it here) *used* to work previously (when I was using a GUI, mikTEX, I think), but now produces the same erroneous output when compiled via pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian), which makes me think it’s not the code itself which is causing problems, but some configuration I may have missed.

How do I get the nodes to adhere to the given positioning?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With your MWE I can't reproduce showed images. It gives image as expected. Do you sure, that your images is generated by provided code?

Comment: I am positive that this image is rendered by the code above (I just copied it from my text editor and pasted it here). As I said, I feel like this is more a configuration problem than an issue with TikZ. (It worked before!)

Comment: Are you perhaps looking at the DVI file with `xdvi`? Don't: `xdvi` is not capable of interpreting the specials used by PGF.

Comment: I was using Envince (the standard application for Ubuntu 14.04). But you’re right anyway. Viewing the generated pdf file with Envice displays everything as expected. I didn’t expect a difference, so I skipped the extra option when compiling.

Would you be so kind to post your comment as answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Note that @egreg would not have been notified of your comment because you didn't use `@username`, as I did here. Also, this same thing has come up before (see e.g. [Tikz with positioning does not work with DVI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5826)), so I'm going to vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: See also [TikZ/PGF figures messed in DVI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84182)

Comment: Of course you’re right. I didn’t think this would have anything to do with DVI (which I thought to be quite equal to PDF), so I didn’t explicitly look for that, and it didn’t come up in the auto-search while typing the question, either.

Thanks for the notification hint. I mistook the term “owner of the post” to be the owner of the last comment. @TorbjørnT.