# Problem using Tikz with IguanaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, powerpoint

I am using IguanaTeX to add formulas and graphs to a powerpoint presentation. I would like to make a few graphs with Tikz. However, IguanaTeX only visualizes the text, and moreover all the letters overlap.

For instance, trying to plot the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\y,red]  plot ({\y*\y},{\y});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Only produces the following:

[image: Pretty inaccurate plot]

where it should produce

[image: Much better]

I am not sure what might be causing this, as in various pages people hint at the fact that tikz does in general work with IguanaTeX.

Comment: Probably (I don't know) IguanaTeX compiles to DVI which it then converts to PNG, and TikZ generally doesn't work in DVI, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/tikz-pgf-figures-messed-in-dvi or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/tikz-with-positioning-does-not-work-with-dvi

Comment: Oh right, using pdflatex solved it, so I guess that was it. Thank you!