# Lattice Node Label Overwritten by All Other Node Labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I run the following code, the label for node V gets overwritten by all the other node labels.  How can this problem be fixed?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\title{Insert Title Here}
\author{Name of Author}
\date{Date}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%-|SECTION 1
\section{A New Section}
New text goes here.  The introduction has yet to be written.  This 
work is still in progress.  But first, I need to create a lattice
diagram.
\hfill\null\\[36pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node(V){$F$};
\node(u)[below=of V]{$G$};
\node(s)[left=of u]{$H$};
\node(b)[right=of u]{$J$};
\node(e)[below=of u]{$K$};
\draw (V) -- (s);
\draw (V) -- (u);
\draw (V) -- (b);
\draw (s) -- (e);
\draw (u) -- (e);
\draw (b) -- (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill\null\\[9pt]
More text goes here.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no problem. The $F$ is clearly visible.

Comment: By overwritten, do you mean all the nodes end up in the same place? Are you by any chance looking at a DVI file? (If you are, try with `pdflatex` instead of `latex`, and look at the PDF.)

Comment: By overwritten I mean that the labels G, H, J, and K are written to the same location where the label F is written.  Ulrike: If you see no problem, then maybe it's related to my DVI viewer.  As Torbjorn suggests, I will take a look at the pdf output.  Thanks.

Comment: Based on Ulrike's and Torbjorn's response I decided to look at the pdflatex output.  The pdf output displayed a lattice diagram with no issues (problems).  Obviously then, the DVI viewer is at fault.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error is in faulty dvi viewer as OP reported.

Comment: I would agree with this being as off-topic since the root cause is a faulty dvi viewer.  Close the question.

Comment: You're mistaken, it's not the DVI viewer that is faulty. Closing as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/tikz-with-positioning-does-not-work-with-dvi or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/tikz-pgf-figures-messed-in-dvi would have been more appropriate.