# The horizontal lines are appearing slanted in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

I was learning to draw a picture with `tikz` package.

When I view the `dvi` file the output is different. The horizontal lines are appearing slanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: TikZ generally doesn't work with DVI (why are you still using DVI anyway?), make a PDF and you should be fine. See  e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826

Comment: Yes, It is the problem with the dvi viewer and got it right after I used pdflatex. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What do you intend for *slanted* ?

Your lines go straight from the initial points to the end ones you indicated in the coordinates.

If you want vertical or horizontal lines, just change the coordinates, see the red lines below.

Moreover, put the grid and the lines in the same `tikzpicture` if you want they overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (6,6);
    \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
    \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
    \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
    \draw[red, very thick] (-1,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[red, very thick] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
    \filldraw[red] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[above right] {Intersection point};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]