# Edge/vertex labels in tikz - Disctinct behavior in book or standalone documentclass

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs

Certainly I'm new using tikz; my current problem is that creating a simple graph, its edge labels behave correct if I use standalone document class but in book class edge labels appear all in the same place which not correspond to the desired one. I have tried changing edge parameters in \path or \draw but without success. Anyone has suggestions or knows how can i fix this in the book class?

My text document is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,intersections,quotes}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[position=bottom]{subfig} %for subfloat

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]} %For tikz picture
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt]
```

%polar coordinates
    \vertex (w) at (18:1) {};
    \vertex (w1) at (3:1.5) {};
    \vertex (w2) at (33:1.5) {};

```
\vertex (u) at (90:1) {};
\vertex (u1) at (75:1.5) {};
\vertex (u2) at (105:1.5) {};

\vertex (v) at (162:1) {};
\vertex (v1) at (147:1.5) {};
\vertex (v2) at (177:1.5) {};

\vertex (x) at (234:1) {};
\vertex (x1) at (219:1.5) {};
\vertex (x2) at (249:1.5) {};

%\draw[gray, fill=gray]  (0.76,-1.1) circle (0.7);
\begin{scope}[]
\vertex[label=left:{$x$}] (y)  at (306:1) {};
\vertex (y1) at (291:1.5) {};
\vertex (y2) at (321:1.5) {};
\end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
    \draw (v) edge (u);
    \end{scope}
    \path 
    (u) edge (w)
    (v) edge (x)
    (x) edge [above, "$U$"] (y)
    (w1) edge (w2)
    (w) edge (w1)
    (w) edge (w2)
    (u) edge (u1)
    (u) edge (u2)
    (u1) edge (u2)
    (v) edge (v1)
    (v) edge (v2)
    (v1) edge (v2)
    (x) edge (x1)
    (x) edge (x2)
    (x1) edge (x2)
    (y) edge (y1) 
    (y) edge (y2)
    (y1) edge (y2)
;
\draw[loosely dotted,thick] (w)--(y);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which shows the output:
[image]

The file using standalone is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph,tkz-berge} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]} %For tikz picture
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt]
%polar coordinates
\vertex (w) at (18:1) {};
\vertex (w1) at (3:1.5) {};
\vertex (w2) at (33:1.5) {};

\vertex (u) at (90:1) {};
\vertex (u1) at (75:1.5) {};
\vertex (u2) at (105:1.5) {};

\vertex (v) at (162:1) {};
\vertex (v1) at (147:1.5) {};
\vertex (v2) at (177:1.5) {};

\vertex (x) at (234:1) {};
\vertex (x1) at (219:1.5) {};
\vertex (x2) at (249:1.5) {};

%\draw[grey, fill=gray]  (0.76,-1.1) circle (0.7);
\vertex (y) at (306:1) {};
\vertex (y1) at (291:1.5) {};
\vertex (y2) at (321:1.5) {};

    \draw (v) edge ["x"] (u);
    \path 
    (u) edge (w)
    (v) edge (x)
    (x) edge ["$U$"] (y)
    (w1) edge (w2)
    (w) edge (w1)
    (w) edge (w2)
    (u) edge (u1)
    (u) edge (u2)
    (u1) edge (u2)
    (v) edge (v1)
    (v) edge (v2)
    (v1) edge (v2)
    (x) edge (x1)
    (x) edge (x2)
    (x1) edge (x2)
    (y) edge (y1) 
    (y) edge (y2)
    (y1) edge (y2)
;
\draw[loosely dotted,thick] (w)--(y);
    %\foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,0.75}
    %\fill ($(w)!\i!(y)$) circle[radius=1pt]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and it shows:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, welcome. If I do this: 1) remove `\begin{figure} \centering` (no `\end{figure}` present, and a `figure` environment won't work in `standalone`) 2) remove `\usepackage{algorithm}` (both it and `algorithm2e` define an `algorithm` environment, so you get an error if you load both) 3) remove `sagetex`,`tkz-berge`,`tkz-graph` (I don't have them, but I wouldn't think they're relevant anyway) 4) change `grey` to `gray` (you get an error that the key `/tikz/grey` is unknown). Then the code works, and I get the same output with either `book` or `standalone` (but not the output you show).

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. : From book class i remove \begin{figure} \centering \end{figure} section were tikzpicture is in. I use algorithm package only, and modify grey to gray as  you pointed out, unfortunately but problem continues. My errors are in book class but i don't know where. Well, the single tex file that i use was mixing code for tikz figure (tikz-graph notation), but i deleted them, using this single graph.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If yes, which? Can you change your code into a single, complete document, that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sure @TorbjørnT. i will attach the file (Kile shows no errors) in a new answer.

Comment: Please don't add code in answers, edit the question instead. This site doesn't work quite like a normal forum, all answers-posts should contain solutions to the problem posed in the question-post, not additional information.

Comment: I see from the screenshot of Kile that you're viewing the DVI-file. Don't. Positioning of nodes doesn't work properly in DVI (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/), use `pdflatex` to make a PDF directly, and it will be correct.

Comment: Yes it works! DVI positioning moves my labels. Thank you @TorbjørnT.